# How can I publish documentation when pushing a NuGet package to nuget.org?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, blazor

I'm building a Blazor component and want to automate the build process. Currently the package builds properly and is pushed to `nuget.org` with its proper license and icon files but I can't find anywhere how to include docs. I have to manually sign in to `nuget.org` and update the docs to point to the same github readme link.

Is there any way to automate this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature is only for `nuget.org` website and is not a part of nuget cli now. And you are not the only one who wants to reflect this problem.

There is [a similar github link](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6873).

**After** feedback from many users, the Team is working hard to add this feature to nuget cli. You can follow this link to keep track of the progress.

Comment: I was hoping there would be an endpoint in `nuget.org` to push docs as well as packages :( I'll be following that conversation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All the data for your package should be included inside the library project (Properties). Once you build the library and upload to Nuget, the links, descriptions and everything else will be displayed when someone searched for your package and previews on visual studio or on Nuget.

Take a look here, you will see where to find everything: https://youtu.be/FTnua-kh-bY